# Hyperledger installation grpc error

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to start learning blockchain development using Hyperledger but have run into an installation error. It seems to be a problem with grpc but I can't figure out exactly where the problem lies. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
1 error generated.░⸩ ⠴ install: info lifecycle grpc@1.10.1~install: Failed to exec install script
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/node" "/Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/oscarstein/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/oscarstein/.npm/_logs/2018-07-02T19_06_50_653Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I don't think that Node v10.x is supported.  Can you try using Node 8.9.x?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the current LTS version which is currently Node version 8. You can use nvm to install the latest lts version with the command `nvm install --lts`